# Retrieving Data From XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having trouble accessing some of the nested data in the XML file. I can get data such as 'ItemID' by using Item->ItemID but I cannot get the data inside 'ItemSpecifics'.

For example, how would I access Colour or Mileage in ItemSpecifics?

I have tried Item->ItemSpecifics->Mileage and Item->ItemSpecifics[1]->Colour with no luck.

This is what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSingleItemResponse 
  xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2020-04-13T11:05:22.064Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Build>E1141_CORE_APILW_19170841_R1</Build>
  <Version>1141</Version>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>283814879195</ItemID>
    <EndTime>2020-04-14T13:58:36.000Z</EndTime>
    <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MERCEDES-CL-CL55-Auto-CL55-AMG-Black-Semi-Auto-Petrol-2003-/283814879195</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
    <ListingType>LeadGeneration</ListingType>
    <Location>Swindon</Location>
    <GalleryURL>https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/pict/2838148791958080_1.jpg</GalleryURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/XrkAAOSwO5Vd8Qph/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/pasAAOSwJkFd8Qpg/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/5lcAAOSwBi5d8Qph/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/~dYAAOSwK~td8Qph/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/xHsAAOSw3t1d8Qpg/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/60wAAOSwWEdd8Qpg/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyNVgxNTAw/z/A3cAAOSwhYNd8Qpg/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
    <PrimaryCategoryID>9855</PrimaryCategoryID>
    <PrimaryCategoryName>Cars, Motorcycles &amp; Vehicles:Cars:Mercedes-Benz</PrimaryCategoryName>
    <BidCount>0</BidCount>
    <ConvertedCurrentPrice currencyID="GBP">4495.0</ConvertedCurrentPrice>
    <ListingStatus>Active</ListingStatus>
    <TimeLeft>P1DT2H53M14S</TimeLeft>
    <Title>MERCEDES CL CL55 Auto CL55 AMG Black Semi-Auto Petrol, 2003 </Title>
    <ItemSpecifics>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Previous owners</Name>
        <Value>4</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Colour</Name>
        <Value>Black</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Mileage</Name>
        <Value>146951</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Power</Name>
        <Value>360</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Engine Size</Name>
        <Value>5439</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Year</Name>
        <Value>2003</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Manufacturer</Name>
        <Value>Mercedes-Benz</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Model</Name>
        <Value>Other</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Body Type</Name>
        <Value>Other</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Doors</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Seats</Name>
        <Value>4</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Transmission</Name>
        <Value>Semi-Automatic</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Fuel</Name>
        <Value>Petrol</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Reg. Date</Name>
        <Value>20030114</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>MOT Expiry</Name>
        <Value>202006</Value>
      </NameValueList>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Reg. Mark</Name>
        <Value>**52 *** &lt;a target=&quot;_JumpPage&quot; href=&quot;http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewJumpPageForVehicleHistory&amp;vrm=Uk41MkVWUg%3D%3D&amp;vrm_d=**52 ***&quot;&gt;Get the Vehicle Status Report &lt;/A&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/uk/motors/vsr_logo_small.gif&quot; width=&quot;20&quot; height=&quot;20&quot; alt=&quot;VSR&quot; align=&quot;middle&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; &gt;</Value>
      </NameValueList>
    </ItemSpecifics>
    <Country>GB</Country>
    <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
    <ConditionID>3000</ConditionID>
    <ConditionDisplayName>Used</ConditionDisplayName>
  </Item>
</GetSingleItemResponse>
```

Comment: mileage or colour are xml values, you can't access them like that ; to search for some values for a given tag (here 'name'), you have to use a xpath search. See PHP manual for xpath and SimpleXml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the colour is in a list of name/value elements, you would be better off using XPath to search for the correct pair.  As the XML has a default namespace(the `xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"` bit), you also have to register that to be able to use a prefix in your XPath.

This uses `//d:NameValueList[d:Name="Colour"]`, but it is looking for a element with the value `Colour` in the `<NameValueList>` list.  `xpath()` always returns a list of matches, so use `[0]` to get the first one.  This also gives you the `<NameValueList>` item, so use `$colour[0]->Value`...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
$colour = $xml->xpath('//d:ItemSpecifics/d:NameValueList[d:Name="Colour"]');
echo $colour[0]->Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't call it by its `Value` (Mileage & Colour). You call it by its `Key`

`Item->ItemSpecifics[0]->Name` should return `Previous owners`
`Item->ItemSpecifics[0]->Value` should return `4`

Comment: This answers how to access  the name and values, but not how to get the Colour value.